# Parsing XML to an object / class + mapping in c# mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

The project I'm working on is an Extranet. I need to call a webservice in this project that communicates with the database. This works as an APPserver. 
The procedures between the APPserver and the database are written in Progress. The output that I receive from the webservice is an object that contains XML.

Is it possible to convert the XML file to objects? For example, I have a node

```
<user>
    <uid></uid>
    <lastname></lastname>
    <firstname></firstname>
</user>
```

Can this user node convert to a User entity?

The complexity is much higher when it starts with relationships. How the XML will look like, I can't really say at this time.

Are there any other possible frameworks / languages I could use, so they simplify this process?

What will happen with the structure of the relationships and how to handle them?

Answer (score 1):

This example is from an old version of .NET, but it is still relevant.  Use XML deserialization to load objects based on an XML format.  You can have nested classes.  Just decorate all classes/properties as necessary to create the proper format when the object is serialized, and you'll be able to deserialize XML into objects back at the webservice.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4491/Load-and-save-objects-to-XML-using-serialization